# Css not changing using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a ul with 2 li's in there, and a local map. if the user hovers on one of the li's the map lights up on of the regions, when the user hovers on one of the regions the corresponding li should light up.

It actually works, but it doesn't work for a 100%, the only one thing that changes is the padding, but the color doesn't change and the list style doesn't change.

```
<ul>         
<li id="selector1"><a href="#">area 1</a></li>
<li id="selector2"><a href="#">area 2</a></li>
</ul>


$(function() {
    $('#area-1').hover(function() {
        $('#selector-1').css({
            'list-style':'square',
            'padding':'.5em 0',
            'color':'#0a6480',
        });
    }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the color
        $('#selector-1').css({
            'list-style':'none',
            'padding':'.2em 0',
            'color':'#FFF'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please revise your snippets to help clarify your question? What is `#area-1`? Are `#selector-1` and `id="selector1"` supposed to be the same (mismatched hyphen)? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

'list-style' is suppsoed on the 'UL' element,
'color' is supposed to go on the 'A' element

Example of code:

```
<ul>         
<li id="selector1"><a href="#">area 1</a></li>
<li id="selector2"><a href="#">area 2</a></li>
</ul>


$(function() {
    $('#area-1').hover(function() {
        $('#selector-1').css({'padding':'.5em 0'});
        $('#selector-1').closest('ul').css({'list-style':'square'});
        $('#selector-1').find('a').css({'color':'#0a6480'});
    }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the color
        $('#selector-1').css({'padding':'.2em 0'});
        $('#selector-1').closest('ul').css({'list-style':'none'});
        $('#selector-1').find('a').css({'color':'#FFF'});            
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, JavaScript contains `#selector-1`, while in HTML it's `#selector1` (hyphen).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help! EDIT: do you know if it's possible to add transitions in the js?

Comment: @tehchriis Here's the [animate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that your id is **selector1** but you are trying to find **selector-1** id element. By the way, I supposed that area-1 is the link inside the first list item:

```
<ul>
  <li id="selector1"><a id="area-1" href="#">area 1</a></li>
  <li id="selector2"><a href="#">area 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/g2bynfdg/

Answer (score 0):

If you target the selector, then you can use $(this) to work with that DOM node. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/5f9eyxc3/). The area 1 link will change styles when hovering on/off of that link.

**HTML**

```
<ul>         
  <li id="selector-1"><a href="#">area 1</a></li>
  <li id="selector-2"><a href="#">area 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#selector-1').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'list-style':'square',
            'padding':'.5em 0',
            'color':'#0a6480'
        });
    }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the color
        $(this).css({
            'list-style':'none',
            'padding':'.2em 0',
            'color':'#FFF'
        });
    });
});
```